# vertical align NAV into HEADER

Tags: html, css, header

I have a fixed header with a `<nav>` into it. The problem is that I tried a lot of things, but my elements don't vertically align on middle. I cannot use `line-height` because it depends on screen resolution.

**CSS**

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 15%;
    background-color: rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.75);
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    overflow: hidden;
}

header nav {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;

}

header nav a {
    /*line-height: 6;*/
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <div>
        <nav>
            <a class="active" href="">Home</a>
            <a href="">News</a>
            <a href="">Info</a>
            <a href="">Contact</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/JJ8Jc/4082/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use display flex method to align elements vertically and/or horizontally

I just added

```
 header nav {
 display:flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
```

so you example now become:

```css
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 15%;
    background-color: rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.75);
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    overflow: hidden;
    display:flex;
}

header nav {
    text-align: center;
    display:flex;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

header nav a {
    /*line-height: 6;*/
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div>
        <nav>
            <a class="active" href="">Home</a>
            <a href="">News</a>
            <a href="">Info</a>
            <a href="">Contact</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

on your `.nav` css, change `top: 0;` for `top: 50%;` then add these lines:

```
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

and remove `bottom: 0;`

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/m9Lenzno/)

*Alternatively, you could use `padding-bottom` and `padding-top` to increase the header size keeping the content on the middle. Or, yet, let it flex like the other answer has already suggested.*

```css
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 15%;
    background-color: rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.75);
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    overflow: hidden;
}

header nav {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

header nav a {
    /*line-height: 6;*/
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div>
        <nav>
            <a class="active" href="">Home</a>
            <a href="">News</a>
            <a href="">Info</a>
            <a href="">Contact</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```